# A small part of an application window is cut and displayed over other application windows

Tags: 14.04, gnome, skype, ubuntu-gnome, window

A small part of my screen gets cut and appears on other screens in Ubuntu 14.04?

I am using Skype. While texting on Skype, I suddenly move to other apps. This small area is cut from Skype and appears in other apps.

[image: Small screen goes all over the apps]

Comment: Does this only happen with skype?

Comment: No,... Every time even it comes from terminal, chrome, eclipse,.. etc

Comment: @Robby1212 Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and it went away.